# Conditional JSON Request mapping in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a post request with URL `http://my-custom-url/{param}`

now

```
//pseudo code
if param == param1
then request body must be mapped to model Class A
if param == param2
then request body must be mapped to model Class B
```

In addition to mapping I also have Jsr303 validation inside my model class es hence I also want to use @Valid annotation
How do I do this

Comment: When asking homework questions, show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having to give us a better understanding of your intentions, what you might be doing wrong, and your goal. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Comment: If Class A and Class B are entities in an inheritance hierarchy then all this could be handled transparently without any conditionals  but you have not actually posted any relevant code so it is not possible to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the payload as a `Map<K, V>` and use `ObjectMapper` to deserialize it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/my-rest-api")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    ClassAValidator classAValidator; // assuming you wrote an validator

    @Autowired
    ClassBValidator classBValidator; // assuming you wrote an validator

    @PostMapping("/{parameter}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleRequest(
            @PathVariable("parameter") String parameter,
            @RequestBody Map<Object, Object> request,
            BindingResult result) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if (parameter.equals("X")) {
           ClassA classA = mapper.convertValue(request, ClassA.class);
           classAValidator.validate(classA, result);
           if(result.hasErrors()) {
                throw new CustomException(result);
           }
        } else if (parameter.equals("Y")) {
            ClassB classB = mapper.convertValue(request, ClassB.class);
            classBValidator.validate(classB, result);
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                throw new CustomException(result);
            }
        } else {
            // ..
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
    }

}
```

Comment: I also want to use @ Valid annotation I have few validation

Comment: I don't think you can use `@Valid` that way. One alternative is to programatically call your validator (assuming you've wrote one). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is a simpler solution:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my-custom-url")
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/param1")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleClassA(
            @Valid @RequestBody ClassA classA,
            BindingResult result) {
        ...
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
    }

    @PostMapping("/param2")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleClassB(
            @Valid @RequestBody ClassB classB,
            BindingResult result) {
        ...
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Ok");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why above answers explaining validators. as I understand you are trying to return two type of responses based on condition. that is not possible. because return type validate on compile time. so if you set return type as classA you must return classA. you cannot return classB. (unless classB is a classA relationship) so if you really want to do this you can use name interface to enforce the type.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Response getRent(@PathVariable int id, @RequestParam(required = false) String type) {

        if(type=="A"){
            return  new ClassA(rentService.findById(id));
        }else{
         return    new ClassB (rentService.findDetailResponse(id));
        }
    }
```

P.S: you may need to return this as

```java
public ResponseEntiry<Response>
```

but I just used Response directly.

now you need to create those two classes from same interface

```java
public interface Response {
}
```

```java
public class ClassA implements Response {
// your code goes here
}
```

```java
public class ClassB implements Response {
// code here
}
```

this way you can achieve what you are trying.

Comment: No I am not trying to send 2 different response but trying to receive 2 different Objects as a request body in post request based on value of Path variable

Comment: Then its simple. do the same way I did. but opposite way.